# "Cannot use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image as Image because the name is already in use"

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I am trying to figure out how to use Intervention Image library but I'm getting this error. I followed the Laravel integration on their website which had me do the following.

After you have installed Intervention Image, open your Laravel config file config/app.php and add the following lines.

In the `$providers` array add the service providers for this package.

```
Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class
```

Add the facade of this package to the `$aliases` array.

```
'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class
```

I have a model called `Image.php` and I'm not sure if that matters.

```
'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
        Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,

        /*
         * Package Service Providers...
         */

        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

    ],
```

Aliases

```
'aliases' => [

        'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
        'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
        'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
        'Blade' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
        'Broadcast' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast::class,
        'Bus' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
        'Cache' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
        'Config' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
        'Cookie' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
        'Crypt' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
        'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
        'Eloquent' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
        'Event' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
        'File' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
        'Gate' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
        'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
        'Lang' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
        'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
        'Mail' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
        'Notification' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::class,
        'Password' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
        'Queue' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
        'Redirect' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
        'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
        'Request' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
        'Response' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
        'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
        'Schema' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
        'Session' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
        'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
        'URL' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
        'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
        'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
        'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class

    ],
```

Image Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Image extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function tags(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag','tag_image','image_id','tag_id');
    }

    public function votes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Vote');
    }
}
```

Comment: somewhere you have duplicated it. show your full code of providers array, and model

Comment: I've added them.

Comment: these looks fine, check your controller you may used double time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably an error caused by the [auto-discovery](https://medium.com/@taylorotwell/package-auto-discovery-in-laravel-5-5-ea9e3ab20518) feature introduced in Laravel 5.5.

Since the package is automatically registering the alias and you are registering manually it ends up being duplicated.

To solve it remove the service provider and the alias from the file and try to use it directly. You can check if the package is auto discovered when you execute a `composer dumpautoload`, it will generate an output like:

```
Generating optimized autoload files
Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
@php artisan package:discover
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy 
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Package manifest generated successfully.
```

It should show the `intervention/image` package discovered. You can check this behaviour implemented in their [`composer.json`](https://github.com/Intervention/image/blob/master/composer.json#L37).

Now in  order to use both classes at the same time you would need to assign a new alias to one of them like:

```
use Image as InterventionImage;
use App\Image;
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I removed the service provider and the alias, used composer dupautoload and got a message that intervention/images package has been discovered. I'm just not sure what do you mean by "try to use it directly"?

Comment: @Bobimaru Your class named `Image` was not causing the error, it was caused by setting two aliases with the same name, now you shouldn't get any errors

Comment: But I still do for some reason ;(. Could it be because I use "use App\Image;" and "use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;"

Comment: @Bobimaru Of course, if you are using both at the same time you need to change one of them with the `as` keyword, check out the updated answer

Comment: Is the Image $img = Image::make('public/uploads/images/'.$fileNameToStore)->resize(300, 200); gonna refer to my Image model or InterventionImage?